# Swift - MapView intermittently shows annotation title/subtitle as blank

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

My iOS map view shows an initial annotation. I want the user to be able to click on the map and for the annotation to move to the spot where the user clicked, but to retain the non-coordinate information in the annotation (e.g. title, subtitle). The code below works, but intermittently the title and subtitle are not showing (see animation and that the name "Spot Name" sometimes doesn't show). It's unclear to me why this is occurring. If I add print statements to print spot.name and spot.title after mapView.addAnnotation, the String values are there & remain unchanged in the MKAnnotation conforming class. Also, when I click in the marker, the proper title and subtitle show in the callout, even if they weren't showing in the annotation. Grateful for any advice/corrections. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class SpotDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var spot: Spot! // Spot class conforms to NSObject & MKAnnotation

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        spot = Spot()
        spot.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.334709, longitude: -71.170061)
        spot.name = "Spot Name"
        spot.address = "Spot Address, Spot Town, Spot State"

        // Set initial region
        let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 250
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(spot.coordinate, regionDistance, regionDistance)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        mapView.addAnnotation(self.spot)
    }


    @IBAction func mapViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let annotationView = mapView.view(for: mapView.annotations[0])
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)
        guard !(annotationView?.frame.contains(touchPoint))! else {
            return
        }
        let newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        spot.coordinate = newCoordinate
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        mapView.addAnnotation(self.spot)
        mapView.setCenter(spot.coordinate, animated: true)
    }
}

extension SpotDetailViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let identifer = "Marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifer) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifer)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is happening to me as well. When I receive the user's destination, I add an annotation for their current location and their destination, and set the title for each, yet occasionally, the title's don't show.

Comment: What if you do `view.titleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibility.visible`?